# Which timer is tick timer in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86-64, interrupt, scheduling

Which timer interrup trigger cfs?
When I run `cat /proc/interrupts` command, I just seeing local timer interrupt changes in timer peripherals?
Which timer is tick timer in linux in x86 architecture?

I actually wonder which timer is equavelent of system tick timer in cortex-m in x86? For example, linux uses ttc (trimple timer counter) as tick timer in zynq series soc. But i couldn't understand which timer is used as tick timer in x86. While content of /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksources file is acpi_pm,hpet,tsc, content of current_clocksource is tsc. But there aren't any of these peripheral's interrupt in output of `cat /proc/interrupts`

Comment: The [kernel](http://kernel.org/) is free software, so you can study its source code, and is explained in many places.  See https://kernelnewbies.org/; BTW I would guess that most (and probaby *all*) external interrupts are triggering (or could trigger) a context switch. See also [*operating systems: three easy pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Comment: Ok. I wonder which timer is equavelent of system tick timer in cortex-m in x86? For example, linux uses trimple timer counter as tick timer in zynq series soc. But i culdn't understand which timer is used as tick timer in x86.

Comment: You'll better [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53486182/edit) your question to improve it. In general, avoid commenting your own question

Comment: TSC is the CPU timestamp counter, queried with the `rdtsc` instruction -> some scaling when a timestamp is needed.  It doesn't tick.  `/proc/interrupts` should have an entry for local timer interrupts, though.  At least that and probably most other interrupts will call `schedule()` after executing the top-half IRQ handler, to (I think) either run the bottom half or pick another task to execute.

Comment: x86 systems have the following timers: 8251 PIT, always present, very ugly frequency due to legacy and settings. APIC Timer, always present since the P4 with Hyper Threading. A bit hard to find it's ticking frequency but very reliable and flexible. The HPET, very precise and flexible timer. Optional, but usally present on Intel's chipset. I believe that's all the kernel uses but a lot of devices "tick", for example the OHCI/UHCI (USB 1.x) can generate precise 1ms interrupts; the display v-sync ticks at 60-100Hz.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I actually wonder where is jiffies increased?

Comment: @MargaretBloom, unfortunately I have to correct you. PIT is not always present.

Comment: @0andriy Do you have any source to confirm that? The PIT is part of the IBM PC. I don't think there's a standard on x86 hardware, only legacy. That's why I found it hard to believe the PIT can be missing. I may be wrong though.

Comment: @MargaretBloom, of course I have evidence: a) ACPI specification defines PIT is a legacy device and moreover introduced so called Hardware Reduced platform, where is no PIT (yes, we have such platforms); b) line of Intel Atoms called MID do not have legacy devices (PIT, PIC) — means all smartphones on x86 so far.

Comment: @0andriy Nice to know, I weren't aware of the Reduced Hardware platform, thanks for sharing! though I don't consider smartphones part of x86 IBM PC, those of course have total different needs

Comment: @MargaretBloom, Intel Edison IoT module is made out of Intel Merrifield platform (which is from MID line), not a smartphone, though not a full-featured PC.